# email.errors.HeaderParseError: header value appears to contain an embedded header:

Tags: python, security, mime-types, code-injection

I am trying to restore mails using soap messages using office api's but it is giving 'header value appears to contain an embedded header' error for some mails.
eg.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@locmsglhost\r\nSubject: injected subject'
msg.as_string()
```

> is throwing an error as email.errors.HeaderParseError: header value
>   appears to contain an embedded header: 'me@locmsglhost\nSubject: injected subject'

But if I am changing msg['From'] to

```
'hello\r man: man'
'tya: Hello'
'push@#$\r\nPus'
'Hello \n\r Pushpa: World'
'@\r\nhello : World'
```

then it is working as expected.

> What could be the possible reasons and What sort of vulnerabilities
>   would there be in mime message?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use any header as you want, that's forbidden.

As stated in [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.errors.html#email.errors.HeaderParseError),

> *exception email.errors.HeaderParseError*
>
> ... when an attempt is made to create a header that appears to contain an embedded header (that is, there is what is supposed to be a continuation line that has no leading whitespace and looks like a header).

---

**Why it is dangerous and should be handled well?**

First, you may read [this](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/email-header-injection/), it provide a simple example how a SMTP header injection attack can be done.

You may ask how can it be done? I mean you are not letting anyone to edit your backend right?

Let's imagine, for you app there may be some field entered by user, for example `'message'`,

```
msg['message'] = 'abc' #Entered by user
```

That's ok, but what if

```
msg['message'] = 'abc\r\nreplyTo:attacker@hello.com'
#or
msg['message'] = 'abc\r\nTo:attacker@hello.com'
```

Attacker can easily override your email for like sending spam email. That's why it do the check for you.

---

You may even check if the header safe by

```
email.header.Header('string')
```

---

**Let's take a look how python email library do the checking.**

Searching in the source code, `Lib/email/header.py`

In ln50-52:

```
# Find a header embedded in a putative header value.  Used to check for
# header injection attack.
_embedded_header = re.compile(r'\n[^ \t]+:')
```

You may try it, all example you provided can pass it except the one you stated.

As email header structure is always `\n(key_without_space):`, so `\nhello :` passed but not `\nhello:`.

Comment: But it is breaking for cases like 
"877-237-1843\nPassword: 4607",       
    "When: Apr 10, 2014 10:00:00 AM\nWhere: West Palm Beach",     
    "Anoka Stake Center\n6:30 & 7:30pmCT"    
and     "Tuesday, May 1\n8:10-8:40 a.m., Alumni Auditorium".

But it is working for input like this---
'hello\r man: man'
'tya: Hello'
'push@#$\r\nPus'
'Hello \n\r Pushpa: World'
'@\r\nhello : World'.

I don't understand this pattern and what is the rule or regex they are checking it against?